# ROS Version Mismatch: Robot vs Workstation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it necessary to have the same ROS version installed on your workstation as is on your robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222752/ros-version-mismatch:-robot-vs-workstation/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. The ROS versioning policy does not guarantee message compatibility between different versions of ROS.

Most things will work most of the time between versions, but some topics and message types may not work, and tools that assume a newer version of ROS will not work with nodes running on an older version.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1